# How to extract a particular value from log file and transfer it to another file

Tags: shell, text-processing, files, grep

I have a log file which looks like:

```
########### mv90_poll.sh started Wed Sep 23 02:36:00 PDT 2015 ############

/usr/mv90/mv90/system/*.di not found
list *.HHF files in /usr/mv90/fats
-rw-------   1 cdas       cdas             6 Jan 12  2015 MO994001.HHF
-rw-------   1 cdas       cdas        189440 Jan 12  2015 MO994002.HHF
-rw-rw-r--   1 samalrr    cdas         12800 Sep 22 13:30 TU994001.HHF
```

I want to know how to write a script which would extract all the `.HHF` files into another file, may be in excel format.

Comment: Are you looking to go through the log file, and pull out a list of all the *.HFF files in there and log them into another file? Or actually *find* a list of all the .hff files in another directory?

Comment: I will go through the log and pulls out a list of all the .HFF files in their and log them to another file .This log file contain all the HHF file processed

Comment: @Gravy I tried using this grep .HHF mv90_poll.log | grep "mv90" | grep "Sep 23" > test.txt . Its working but the problem is everytime I have to edit the script and change the date . I want the all .HHF files from system date -1 means the previous day . can we make into generic , so that I don't have to change again and again

Answer (score 4):

Use `grep`:

```
grep -oP '[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{6}\.HHF$' file >newfile
```

I assume that those `.HHF` files have a name beginning with 2 uppercase characters (`[A-z{2}]`) and then 6 digits (`[0-9]{6}`), followed by `.HHF`.

---

The `-o` flag forces `grep` to print only the matched part of the pattern, instead of the whole line. `-P` activates Perl compatible regular expressions.

Comment: Don't need `-P` for that pattern, `-E` will do. +1 for `grep -o`

Comment: I tried but the new file does not contain anything

Comment: @Pooja make sure you have either the `-P` or `-E` options added. Based on your test case, I can confirm chaos' answer should work. Shouldn't make a big difference, but what OS are your running this on?

Comment: @Gravy@chaos . I did                                                                    grep .HHF pooja.log | grep "mv90" | grep "Sep" > new file .  I am getting all HHF files processed in that particular week . I want that if run the script on Tuesday , I should get all the HHF files processed on Monday . I want a logic so that I can make the month generic

Answer (score 1):

Another example of a grep command to do the same:

```
$ grep -oE '[[:upper:]]{2}[[:digit:]]{8}\.HHF' the_log_file.log > hhf_list.txt
```

hhf_list.txt:

```
$ cat hhf_list.txt
MO994001.HHF
MO994002.HHF
TU994001.HHF
```

#### How it works

- -o shows only the matched text as @chaos mentioned
- -E uses extended regular expression, so you can type `{` and `}` (curly braces) without escaping them, default grep would require write `\{` and `\}` for the same effect
- I prefer POSIX style `[[:upper:]]` `[[:digit:]]` to make it possibly stand out more, what is being matched, vs the counts `{2}` and `{6}`
- file name with extension .txt optional but helps you remember this is a text file, possibly later if using excel on a windows machine it might be helpful

Comment: its not working

Comment: Can you do a test case, make test_file.txt, containing on line1: `abcabcMO994001.HHFabc` and line 2: `ababaTU994001.HHF` . Then run the command `grep -oE '[[:upper:]]{2}[[:digit:]]{6}\.HHF' test_file.txt` , what do you see? It should be the the HHF files.

Comment: I did grep .HHF pooja.log | grep "mv90" | grep "Sep" > new file . I am getting all HHF files processed in that particular week . I want that if run the script on Tuesday , I should get all the HHF files processed on Monday . I want a logic so that I can make the month generic

Comment: I tried using this grep .HHF mv90_poll.log | grep "mv90" | grep "Sep 23" > test.txt . Its working but the problem is everytime I have to edit the script and change the date . I want the all .HHF files from system date -1 means the previous day . can we make into generic , so that I don't have to change again and again

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to do a similar regex procedure in sed :

```
sed -n 's/.* \([^\s]\{2,\}\.HHF\)/\1/p' log.txt > files.txt
```

The default behaviour of sed is to print out each line in the file you give it (in this case, log.txt). The `-n` flag turns that behaviour off. The `s/REGEXPATTERN/REPLACEMENT/` command will find lines with a substring matching `REGEXPATTERN` and replace it with `REPLACEMENT`. An example of a helper command in sed to do fancy replacement is the `\#` command, where `#` is an integer, which replaces the substring of the line matching the `#`-th part of the `REGEXPATTERN` in parentheses, starting with 1. In this case, it will replace the entire line by just the part of the line that has at least two non-whitespace characters followed by `.HHF`. Finally, the `p` command prints out the resulting modified line, in this case just the filename. Then, we pipe the output with `>` to a text file that will have all your filename stored, one per line. This sed command assumes that your files have at least two characters before the .HHF ending, and it assumes that the filenames will be preceded by at least one space.

Comment: the above sed procedure is working but I am facing a problem that this log contain .HHF file of one week . I want that if I am running the script Tuesday it should send the list of HHF files processed on Monday